# mongodb + nodejs to find and return specific fields in documents

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to [extract specific document fields from a mongodb collection](https://mighty-stream-22541.herokuapp.com/api/subsleeps/20160101/20160103) (v 3.0.8 at MongoLab). The returned documents must fall within a date range. My goal is to extract specific fields from these documents. My nodejs code,

```
var query = {}, operator1 = {}, operator2 = {}, operator3 = {} ;

operator1.$gte = +startDate;
operator2.$lte = +endDate;
operator3.$ne  = 'move';

query['xid'] = 1; // Problem here?
query['date']  = Object.assign(operator1, operator2);
query['type']  = operator3;

console.log(query);

MongoClient.connect(connection, function(err, db) {

    if(err){ 
        res.send(err); 
    } else {
        db.collection('jbone')
          .find(query)
          .toArray(function(err, result){
              console.log(err);
            res.json(result);
            });
    };
});
```

If I opt to return all fields in the date range, the query works fine. If I select only field `xid` I get no results. My `query` object looks sensible according to [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.find/#specify-the-fields-to-return). `console.log(err)` gives:

```
    { xid: 1,
      date: { '$gte': 20160101, '$lte': 20160107 },
      type: { '$ne': 'move' } }
   null
```

`null` is the `err`.

Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Or point me to another similar  SO questions with an answer?

Thanks

Comment: Please check `err` in the callback function, hope it could give more information...

Comment: I updated the Question with the `err` object which only shows `null`

Comment: Is there `xid: 1` related record in `jbone` document?

Comment: I added a link in my question to the data.

Comment: `"xid": "yAtl4PM9ORJEVPZvEu43cHxh3wHHye78"`, the type of xid is `String`, not integer...

Comment: [This link to mongo docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.find/#specify-the-fields-to-return) seems to say `:1` is the `select` option. Have I misunderstood this?

Comment: The select field is another params for query....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select the specific field could be done as below

```
.find( 
  {date: { '$gte': 20160101, '$lte': 20160107 }, type: { '$ne': 'move' }},
  { xid: 1} )
```

Sample codes as following.

```
   query['date']  = Object.assign(operator1, operator2);
   query['type']  = operator3;
    db.collection('jbone')
      .find(query, {xid: 1})
      .toArray(function(err, result){
          console.log(err);
        res.json(result);
        });
```

Comment: Thank you. I completely misread the documentation. Embarrassing amateur mistake!